# chmod a file so all under it are 755

Tags: chmod

i have a so-so problem, the problem is that,from what i understand, 755 is for folders, and 644 is for files, 644 is read only etc...

now my boss says that one of our clients had a WP gallery problem where when they'd upload
a gallery/pictures etc, that not all of them would work. so my boss says "its a permission problem"

Now, when i go in there, its what its supposed to be, the folders are 755, and individual files, 644....

that said, i tell her this is ok, and she says no no the individual files have to be 755 too..so that ppl can see them....i tell her, well 644 is read only so anyone viewing them should have access.

long story short, she wont be satisfied until all files are 755. When i looked at the permission for the parent folder(gallery folder) its also 755.

is there a way to make ALL the inner files 755 instead of doing it one by one manually?

***EDIT- i need to make it so that in the future, whenever a file is uploaded via whatever method(in his case worpress) that it comes in automatically as 755.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursively change permissions

```
chmod 755 -R parent_folder
```

Comment: hello, sorry i edited the question. "i need to make it so that in the future, whenever a file is uploaded via whatever method(in his case worpress) that it comes in automatically as 755." thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having the files themselves 755 is a really weird requirement. The only difference between 644 and 755 is that the files are executable and presumably the files are not being executed.

To fix the files being created with the wrong permissions you can change the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) of the process that is running php (apache?), modify the [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) in php land or change the php code to create the files with the correct permissions. Changing the umask in php or in the process is the least desirable because of the security implications of changing file creation globally.

Answer (score 1):

Googled chmod recursive : http://www.zzee.com/solutions/chmod-help.shtml

check -R property, shoudl do what you need

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply, i edited the question to add this. "i need to make it so that in the future, whenever a file is uploaded via whatever method(in his case worpress) that it comes in automatically as 755." thanks